# Should flip-side and different denomination-based questions be linked as related?

Tags: discussion, questions

When asking [this question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/should-related-question-links-be-edited-into-questions-or-left-as-comments) the question of what constitutes a related question came to mind, in particular for "flip-side" questions (e.g., "What is the argument for X?" and "What is the argument against X?"), though some questions marked as specific to a different denomination could likewise be related (e.g., "Why do Catholics reject X?" and "Why do Lutherans reject X?") even if they could not be merged into a single question (is question merging ever done on Stack Exchange?).

Of course, the "Related" sidebar is supposed to provide some of this function, and I could easily see difficulty with adding too many links.  I wonder if allowing static (human-generated) related questions at the top of the list on the "Related" sidebar would be useful.  (My guess would be that such had already been suggested as a feature request for SE and rejected for practical reasons, but it is *remotely* possible that I might be the first to suggest the possibility of such *and* that it is something useful and practical!  However, I am skeptical enough that I would not present such as a feature request unless at least one or two others confirmed that it might be useful--practical is more for the SE people to decide, I think.)

Answer (score 3):

This is entirely up to the participants in the stream. It may help the site and inform all involved if they are linked, but it might not.

***Please evaluate this on a case by case basis rather than asking for a mandate to do so.***

Yes, you are right that the related sidebar in theory might help, but ultimately that's some algorithm and a human is much better are determining this.

Sometimes, linking two related questions on the flip sides of very controversial question might actually be worse for both questions, so it might be better for them to stay completely separate. However, there is sometimes value in getting them linked so people can see both sides of the issue.

Again, this is a judgement call the participants in the questions should make, it should not be mandated from on high.

Comment: I suspect linking "flip-side" questions would actually work to *prevent* argument, as people see that their opinion is not unrepresented or unwelcome on the site, and therefore feel less need to "push back". But that probably applies more to newer users or to casual visitors than to regulars.

Comment: @TRiG I generally agree

Comment: By the way, I was not seeking a mandate so much as reliable guidelines including what different parts of the community feel.  A single highly upvoted answer without dissenting comments might be a quasi-mandate, but I was thinking that my question might generate more than one response and expose some less obvious concerns.  Personally, I would prefer a legalistic checklist; but having more information available on who my neighbors are might make not loving them properly more culpable/theoretically easier to avoid. :-\